# What approaches can I take to figure out the "relevancy" of certain terms in a string?

Tags: parsing, natural-language-processing, keywords

I'm not even sure "relevancy" is the most accurate word, so I'll just describe the problem:

I'm building an app that needs to somehow parse product descriptions from a popular website (let's just say it's Amazon) and figure out which certifications the product has based on the text in the description alone. The descriptions for these products are not always written the same way (because they're written by different companies), but do always contain certain keywords that I'm looking for -- and the keywords have to be "close together" in the description in order to be considered for the resultset.

For example, given the following CSV data:

```
ProductName,ProductDescription
Product1,Product1 is a really cool product that is certified for Certification1 on Region1
Product2,Product2 has Region2 which has Certification3 and Region3 with Certification4. It also has Certification5
```

I'd want to generate the following output:

```
{  
   "Product1":{  
      "Region1":"Certification1",
      "UnknownRegions": []
   },
   "Product2":{  
      "Region2":"Certification3",
      "Region3":"Certification4",
      "UnknownRegions":[  
         "Certification5"
      ]
   }
}
```

I have almost no idea how to solve this problem, other than one thought: can some NLP algorithm help me to achieve the desired output above? If so, which one? I've heard of a technique called Named Entity Extraction but I don't know if it applies here or not.

Any advice is much appreciated here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The usual term is *Named Entity Recognition*. By searching for that you can find many academic and practical references to such systems. And yes, finding certifications by recurring keywords sounds doable with a little training material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Microsoft LUIS offering

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-service/

I believe amazon have a similar api offering as well.

These allow you to utilise NLP and other AI systems in your apps without having to program your own. You just call the API and get json back with the sentence broken down into subjects and intents.

here is an example of what you get back from LUIS
[image]

Comment: I believe Google has something similar too

Comment: Another resource is the Stanford CoreNLP library, which contains an implementation you can run locally if you don't want to use cloud services.

Comment: @ewan I took a look at Amazon Comprehend, and I'm not sure it does exactly what I want -- it seems to be able to tokenize a document and group tokens by their entity type (i.e. business, place, person, etc) but it doesn't seem to be able to associate entities together unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I've not used that one. It wont do the entire job for you. You need to train it and interpret the results. You can do quite complicated setup, for example "im going from x to y"